# Should I fill this gap between the cement porch and (veneer) brick wall of my house?

Tags: brick, cement

There is a (growing?) gap between a cement porch and the brick casement of my house. Should I fill this, with mortar or some other substance, or leave it alone?

From the marks on the brick, I get the impression that someone has previously filled this gap with mortar, and it has aged away. I don't see any obvious indication that the cement porch is sinking or anything.

[image]

[Here is a link to the original picture](https://imgur.com/Cu4T2Qc)

Comment: Personally, I would.